# Hiding language names in "Language switcher" block and displaying only country flags

Tags: 7

I would like to **hide language names** (like "English", "Español", "Magyar", etc.) **in the "Language switcher" block**, and display only country flags, because I have [Language icons](http://drupal.org/project/languageicons) module installed, and the flags are unambiguous enough for navigating between different languages.

I already set language elements to be displayed in an "inline" style and hide language switcher block's title in my stylesheet file (in a Zen sub-theme) like this:

```css
#block-locale-0 li{
    display:inline;
    list-style-image: none;
}
#block-locale-0 .title{
    display:none;
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

OK, in the meantime I found the perfect solution which I earlier just simply overlooked: there's a really simple configuration option in Language icons module's settings in `http://<yoursite>/admin/settings/language/icons` (D7: `http://<yoursite>/admin/config/regional/language/icons`) .

You have to set "**Icon placement**" option from "Before link" or "After link" to "**Replace link**", which results in displaying only the country flags.

Here are some screenshots (on the admin site I'm currently using [RootCandy](http://drupal.org/project/rootcandy) Dark):

BEFORE:

[image: "Before link" - on the admin site]

AFTER (on the admin site):

[image: "Replace link" - on the admin site]

AFTER (on the main site's right sidebar [design is strongly under development :P]):

[image: The result (only country flags)]